# unable to locate package libapache2-mod-php7.0 Fedora

Tags: php, apache, fedora, apache-config

I want to pass some variables from apache to PHP.The variaible is present in file `/etc/httpd/conf.d/hr3.conf`.

Variabile name: `php_admin_value open_basedir /var/www/html/main_project:/var/www/html/project:/tmp/`

When i check the syntax with httpd -t they give me a error:

```
 AH00526: Syntax error on line 29 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/hr3.conf:
    Invalid command 'php_admin_value', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration.
```

I looked on the internet and i found the missing module (libapache2-mod-php) but i can not found the module for fedora28

Answer (score 1):

```
I am using with fedora 28 with Server version: Apache/2.4.33 (Fedora).
```

> Source https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2017/11/17/Fedora-27-changes-in-http-and-php

Since Fedora 27, mod_php ZTS (multi-threaded) is still provided, but disabled, so FastCGI is now used by default. To not break existing configuration during the distribution upgrade, and to have a working server after installation, They choose to implement some solutions, probably temporarily:

> The php package have a optional dependency on the php-fpm package, so it is now installed by default.
>
> The httpd service have a dependency on the php-fpm service, so it is
>   started automatically

There is no need to download any module, its already present. Need to enable the module in this file `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-mpm.conf`.

In the File Comment this line

```
#LoadModule mpm_event_module modules / mod_mpm_event.so
```

And uncomment this line:

```
LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules / mod_mpm_prefork.so
```

its working for me